# NodeJS "Helloworld"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run one helloworld.js file but it is not working at command prompt level but it is working in my tool named Intellij.
whenever I am running it through command prompt. It prompts one error.

```
module.js:471
throw err;
Error: Cannnot find module"file path"
       at Function.module._resolve Filename<module.js:469:15>
       at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: share come code

Comment: Delete your codes and re-read the tutorial carefully

Comment: if you have a package.json file do ` npm install `

if not install modules manually !

Comment: plz share your helloworld.js file source code

Comment: var express = require('express');


app= express.createServer();

app.get('/',function(req,res){


res.send('Hello world')
});


app.listen();


console.log('Express server started on port %s'app.address().port);

Answer (score 0):

Try install the module ...

npm install "Your Module which was not found"